# OpenGL 1.5 or higher needed by exe file that uses cocos2d-x. How to make it work without video card?

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x, video-card

I tried to build sample projects in cocos2d-x. When I run the exe files, there's a pop window that tells me that OpenGL 1.5 or higher is needed and I should update my drivers. Unfortunately my PC currently don't have video card. Can I upgrade the OpenGL version in my PC without buying a video card?

My PC currently uses **Intel® G33/G31 Express Chipset Family**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Audio-Video-Monitors/opengl-driver-for-intel-g31-g33-chipset/td-p/957541) that **Intel® G33/G31 Express Chipset Family** can support of up to OpenGL 1.4 only. And the only solution to my problem is to buy a video card.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Mesa 3D Graphics Library. From the mesa3d (dot) org website, "Mesa includes a special off-screen rendering interface called OSMesa. It's unique in that the interface has no dependencies on any operating system or window system. Mesa's off-screen rendering interface is quite simple. Documentation for it may be found in the Mesa README file and there is an example program in the Mesa distribution (demos/osdemo.c)."

Comment: Actually, he does not need the "osmesa" renderer, but just the "swrast" software rasterizer, also part of mesa.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. :) I already bought my pc a video card and I can build and run cocos2dx sample project now. :) I just need to cut my expenses since the money is from my allowance.
I'll remember OSMesa so I can consider searching that in the future when I encountered again problems related to this.